# How Can I Select All The Check boxes By Click on a button from action bar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

Here is my RecyclerView Adapter On Each Item i show a check boxes and a save button before save any item user select a check box and save the item  i want user click on a button and all the check boxes are selected and when user click on cancel button all check boxes are unchecked how can i do this

I tried on single check box it work good but for multiple its not work

Comment: Share your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

On save button click call a method inside the adapter to setChecked all items of your data model and call notifyDataSetChanged().